# java print arraylist of interface

Tags: java, arraylist, interface

I'm learning observer design pattern from one of youtube videos and want to understand a bit more the behavior of interface arraylist, I think I quite understand how it works but when it comes the interface arraylist, its confusing to me how to access the value inside loop.

the subject and observer interfaces as follow;

```
public interface Subject {

    public void register(Observer o);
    public void unregister(Observer o);
    public void notifyObserver();

}
```

```
public interface Observer {

    public void updateViaObserver(double ibmPrice, double aaplPrice, double googPrice);

}
```

```
package observer_pattern;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StockGrabber implements Subject{

    private ArrayList<Observer> observers;
    private double ibmPrice;
    private double aaplPrice;
    private double googPrice; 

    public StockGrabber(){

        // Creates an ArrayList to hold all observers

        observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();

    }

    public void register(Observer newObserver) {

        observers.add(newObserver);


    }

    public void notifyObserver() {

        for(Observer observer : observers){

            observer.updateViaObserver(ibmPrice, aaplPrice, googPrice);

        }


    }

    public void setPrice(double newIBMPrice, double newAAPLPrice, double newGOOGPrice){

        this.ibmPrice = newIBMPrice;
        this.aaplPrice = newAAPLPrice;
        this.googPrice = newGOOGPrice;

        notifyObserver();

    }


}
```

```
package observer_pattern;

public class StockObserver implements Observer {

    private double ibmPrice;
    private double aaplPrice;
    private double googPrice;

    private Subject stockGrabber;

    public StockObserver(Subject stockGrabber){

        this.stockGrabber = stockGrabber;

        this.observerID = ++observerIDTracker;

        stockGrabber.register(this);

    }

    // Called to update all observers

    public void updateViaObserver(double ibmPrice, double aaplPrice, double googPrice) {

        this.ibmPrice = ibmPrice;
        this.aaplPrice = aaplPrice;
        this.googPrice = googPrice;

        // this works
        printThePrices();


        // doesn't work
        toString();
    }

    public void printThePrices(){

        System.out.println(observerID + "\nIBM: " + ibmPrice + "\nAAPL: " + 
                aaplPrice + "\nGOOG: " + googPrice + "\n");

    }

    public String toString() {
        return "StockObserver: ibmPrice=" + ibmPrice + " aaplPrice=" + aaplPrice;
    }

}
```

MAIN

```
package observer_pattern;

public class GrabStocks{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        StockGrabber stockGrabber = new StockGrabber();

        StockObserver observer1 = new StockObserver(stockGrabber);

        stockGrabber.setIBMPrice(197.00);
        stockGrabber.setAAPLPrice(677.60);
        stockGrabber.setGOOGPrice(676.40);

        observer1.toString();



    }

}
```

How to access value for my `ArrayList<Observer> observers` inside "notifyObserver" method? if I do this `System.out.println(observers.get(0));` I get observer_pattern.StockObserver@446cdf90

Comment: As long as you add your Observer's to the observers list, then everything should be fine. You can get a better-looking print by overriding the toString() method of the StockObserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to access value for my ArrayList observers inside "notifyObserver" method?

You're already doing it.

```
public void notifyObserver() {
    for(Observer observer : observers){
        observer.updateViaObserver(ibmPrice, aaplPrice, googPrice);
    }
}
```

> if I do this System.out.println(observers.get(0)); I get observer_pattern.StockObserver@446cdf90

That's because your `StockObserver` class does not have a `toString` method that returns a human readable representation of the object. Something like this

```
public String toString() {
    return "StockObserver: ibmPrice=" + ibmPrice + " aaplPrice=" + aaplPrice;
}
```

Comment: When you write `System.out.println(observer)` the `println` method calls `toString`. The `toString` method itself does not print anything, just creates a string that can be printed or used in some other way.

Comment: Yes Joni, I missed that println, now I have what I wanted, thank you so much!